# Sql Server 2008 Partitioning + Identity Column Constraint Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have a table containing huge amount of data I decided to do the partitioning on that table But I am getting some sort of issues please clarify them.

I have an identity column as a primary key ID (int type).

I have done the partitioning by the date column making it also primary key with the combination of  `ID + date`.

Problem is that I am not able to insert the records in partitioning tables because the partitioning view is not able to insert the data due to the identity constraint.
Please help Me.

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the partition (partial) and the table to your question?

Comment: The Partition Function use Int Type, Datetime Type, or other types, but you can't mix data types for Partiton Function , follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have specified the `Identity` of the partitioning Table. If so, then don't specify Identity; otherwise, don't send the primary key through the view.